# Inserting into DB in JPA in play Framework

Tags: templates, groovy, playframework

I am finding difficult to display the template in play framework using groovy

```
#{list users, as:'user'} 
    <li>${user}</li>
#{/list}

#{list items:0..10, as:'i'} 
  ${i}
#{/list}
```

How to combine the above 2 to display like this

1. My Name
2. Plays Name
3. Groovy Name

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by Plays name? Groovy name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is pretty easy to achieve.

To do this in Groovy, using Play, You can simply do

```
#{list users, as:'user'} 
    <li>${user_index}. ${user}</li>
#{/list}
```

See the list tag for more details. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/tags#list

Obviously, you could have just done this with an OrderedList in HTML, using  outside of the List tag, which by default in HTML will show a numbered list.

So, your code could simply be

```
<ol>
#{list users, as:'user'} 
    <li>${user}</li>
#{/list}
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

No real idea of what your example output is meant to show, but I assume you have:

```
<ul>
  #{list users, as:'user'} 
    <li>${user}</li>
  #{/list}
</ul>
```

If you change it to `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`, you will get an ordered list with numbers:

```
<ol>
  #{list users, as:'user'} 
    <li>${user}</li>
  #{/list}
</ol>
```

Comment: That is indeed what I understand of his question.